# Java MS SQL -> mySQL conversion

Tags: java, database, ubuntu-10.04

I have built a Java application that transfers data from a MSSQL db to a mySQL DB.  The problem I have is that the MSSQL db constantly goes down and causes my application to throw exceptions because it can not connect to the server.  Is there a way that I can tell my application to restart if it gets any error?  I am running on Ubuntu 10.04 LTS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't restart it, but depending on the application, you can simulate a restart.

If it is a console application, you can simply call the `main(..)` method again.

If it is a desktop application, you can hide the current `JFrame` and `setVisible(true)` a new `JFrame`